# Communication between robots in gazebo

Tags: ros, communication, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I'm looking for a tool to establish a communication link between 2 or more robots in the Gazebo Simulator. I was thinking in a wireless module but I don't find anything like that.
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/189731/communication-between-robots-in-gazebo/) by [Joao Luis](https://answers.ros.org/users/19882/joao-luis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 110 on 2014-08-11

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kurt Leucht](https://answers.ros.org/users/10621/kurt-leucht/) on 2014-08-11**:
Interesting question.  I think I'm interested in the answer too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Assuming that all the robots are using ROS Topics, they can communicate with each other through Topics that you set up in your onboard robot software.

---

Originally posted by [Kurt Leucht](https://answers.ros.org/users/10621/kurt-leucht/) with karma: 486 on 2016-10-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1